# Spring integration testing without XML

Tags: testing, annotations, junit4, spring-integration, spring-test

Could anyone provide a complete flow test example (channels, gateways, etc) using jUnit4 or other Test tool for spring integration? I am working without XML, thus I prefer a Java-config test initiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your application; for pure annotation configuration start with this [framework test class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/configuration/EnableIntegrationTests.java), it has lots of tests.

If you're using the Java DSL, start [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test).